# Always shows as "Failed"

Tags: conditional-statements, android-toast

I'm new in Android Studio and I'm making a simple Login Form in which the user must input "admin" (Username) and "admin123" (password). If both are true, a toast message will pop up as "Success" and "Failed" otherwise.

However, when I run the code it will always say as "Failed" when all the conditions are met.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                EditText txtuname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtuname);
                EditText txtpassw = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtpassw)

                Toast toast = new Toast(getApplicationContext());
                toast.setGravity(Gravity.TOP | Gravity.LEFT, 0, 0);

                if((txtuname.getText().equals("admin")) && (txtpassw.getText().equals("admin123"))){
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Success",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else{
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Failed",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Code will not compile as-is, there's (at least) a missing semi-colon. You should probably cut'n'paste the code to ensure it's correct. Having said that, you can add debug statements to your code printing out (or msgboxing) the two fields. This may help you establish what the problem is. In any case, doesn't `getText()` return an `Editable`? Don't you have to get the `text` property of that to get the actual string? Not sure (which is why this is a comment rather than an answer) but you may want to look into that.

Comment: I have already resolved the problem. Thanks!